# how to store tasks in temporary storage in flutter (use Shared preferences or something similar)

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a program to create tasks, everything works as it should, I made such options as validation, deleting the task, changing the theme. But the problem is that when I restart the app all the tasks are deleted. I want to keep them in storage, temporarily or permanently. And I can't realize it. Someone may have experience as such to implement ?? or examples of similar problems. My goal is that after restarting the application, all tasks remain.
My code

```html
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main ()  {

  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: App(),
  ));
}

class ListItem{
  String todoText;
  bool todoCheck;
  ListItem(this.todoText, this.todoCheck);
}

class _strikeThrough extends StatelessWidget{

  final String todoText;
  final bool todoCheck;
  _strikeThrough(this.todoText, this.todoCheck) : super();

  Widget _widget(){
    if(todoCheck){
      return Text(
        todoText,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 22.0,

        ),
      );
    }
    else{
      return Text(
        todoText,
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 22.0
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return _widget();
  }
}

class App extends StatefulWidget{

  @override
  AppState createState(){
    return AppState();
  }
}
final ValueNotifier<ThemeMode> _notifier = ValueNotifier(ThemeMode.light);

class AppState extends State<App> {
  bool valText = true;
  var counter = 0;
  var IconsType =  Icons.wb_sunny  ;

  late Color ColorType =  Colors.black;

  var textController = TextEditingController();
  var popUpTextController = TextEditingController();


  List<ListItem> WidgetList = [];

  @override
  void dispose() {
    textController.dispose();
    popUpTextController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    addToSP(defaultList).then((_) => getSP());
    super.initState();
  }
  Future<void> addToSP(List<List<ListItem>> tList) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('graphLists', jsonEncode(tList));
  }

  void getSP() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final List<dynamic> jsonData =
    jsonDecode(prefs.getString('graphLists') ?? '[]');
    WidgetList = jsonData.map<List<ListItem>>((jsonList) {
      return jsonList.map<TodoInfo>((jsonItem) {
        return ListItem.fromJson(jsonItem);
      }).toList();
    }).toList();
    setState(() {});
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder<ThemeMode>(
        valueListenable: _notifier,
        builder: (_, mode, __) {
          return MaterialApp(
              theme: ThemeData.light(),
              darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
              themeMode: mode, // Decides which theme to show, light or dark.
              home: Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  title: Text("Список задач"),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(IconsType,color : ColorType
                        ),
                        onPressed:() =>
                        {
                          if (_notifier.value == ThemeMode.light) {
                            _notifier.value =  ThemeMode.dark,
                            IconsType = Icons.dark_mode,
                            ColorType = Colors.white,

                          } else
                            {
                              _notifier.value =  ThemeMode.light,
                              IconsType = Icons.wb_sunny,
                              ColorType = Colors.black,
                            }
                        }
                    )
                  ],
                  //backgroundColor: Colors.orange[500],
                  iconTheme: IconThemeData(
                      color: Colors.white
                  ),
                ),
                body: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[

                    Container(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,

                        children: <Widget>[
                          const Text(
                            "Tasks",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 70.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                          IconButton(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            iconSize: 70,
                            constraints: const BoxConstraints(),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 10.0, 30, 10.0),
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.add_outlined),
                            onPressed: ()  {
                              if (textController.text.replaceAll(" ", "").isNotEmpty) {
                                WidgetList.insert(0, new ListItem(textController.text.replaceAll(" ", ""), false));
                                setState(() {
                                  valText = true;
                                  textController.clear();

                                });
                              }
                              else
                              {
                                setState(() {
                                  valText = false;
                                });
                              }
                            },


                          )




                        ],
                      ),

                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery
                          .of(context)
                          .size
                          .height * 0.45,
                      child: TextField(

                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 22.0,
                          //color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                        ),
                        controller: textController,
                        cursorWidth: 5.0,
                        autocorrect: true,
                        autofocus: true,
                        //onSubmitted: ,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Align(
                        child:
                        (valText == false) ?
                        Align(child: Text(("Задача пустая"),
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 25.0, color: Colors.red)),
                            alignment: Alignment.center) :
                        Align(child: Text((""),),
                            alignment: Alignment.center)),
                    Expanded(
                      child: ReorderableListView(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          for(final widget in WidgetList)
                            GestureDetector(
                              key: Key(widget.todoText),
                              child: Dismissible(
                                key: Key(widget.todoText),
                                child: CheckboxListTile(
                                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                                  //key: ValueKey("Checkboxtile $widget"),
                                  value: widget.todoCheck,
                                  title: _strikeThrough(
                                      widget.todoText, widget.todoCheck),
                                  onChanged: (checkValue) {
                                    //_strikethrough toggle
                                    setState(() {
                                      if (!checkValue!) {
                                        widget.todoCheck = false;
                                      }
                                      else {
                                        widget.todoCheck = true;
                                      }
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                                background: Container(
                                  child: Icon(Icons.delete),
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                                ),

                                direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                                movementDuration: const Duration(
                                    milliseconds: 200),
                                onDismissed: (dismissDirection) { //Delete Todo
                                  WidgetList.remove(widget);

                                },
                              ),
                            )
                        ],
                        onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
                          setState(() {
                            if (newIndex > oldIndex) {
                              newIndex -= 1;
                            }
                            var replaceWiget = WidgetList.removeAt(oldIndex);
                            WidgetList.insert(newIndex, replaceWiget);
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
          );
        }
    );
  }
}

class TodoInfo {
  String todoText;
  bool todoCheck;

  TodoInfo({
    required this.todoText,
    required this.todoCheck,

  });

  factory TodoInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return TodoInfo(
        todoText: json["todoText"],
        todoCheck: json["todoCheck"]);
  }

  factory TodoInfo.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) => TodoInfo(
    todoText: map["todoText"]?? '',
    todoCheck: map["todoCheck"] ?? '',

  );
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      "todoText": todoText,
      "todoCheck": todoCheck
    };
  }

  @override
  String toString() => '{todoText: $todoText, todoCheck: $todoCheck}';
}
```

My skrin
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are some options for [persistent memory](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence).

Answer (score 0):

You could use any of the storage functions/plugins available for flutter as per your need or interest.
Some of them are

1. [Seflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite)
2. [Shared preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)
3. [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive)

Example on how to use Shared Preferences: [LINK](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-sharedpreferences-in-flutter-to-store-data-locally/)

Comment: Thanks, I've reviewed the options, and since I'm new to these packages, I think Shared preferences  are the best option, but I can't figure it out. I will save my list locally and download it from the repository before downloading the program. But how to delete one of the elements of the list and not keep the list, tell me ?? Thank you)

Comment: you just have to fetch the list from the storage, remove the item you want from the list and save the updated list back to the storage

Comment: sounds simple, but for me it is not very clear how to do it))

Comment: I have updated the answer with an example. Hope that helps you

Comment: hank you, I saw this example, and here the guilt is clear, but there are only different types of data in the example, and how to save the list is not) but thank you, I will look for how to implement your idea)

Comment: you could save the list by encoding the json list into the string and parse it by decoding it into the list again.

Please mark the answer if it helps you

Comment: ok but can you tell me more about coding in the list ?? i have my list back up ?? List <ListItem> WidgetList = []; ??

Comment: here is the simple example for that: https://flutterhq.com/questions-and-answers/1487/how-to-save-listlistobject-list-to-shared-preferences-flutter

Comment: I edited all the code(in question), according to the example that was dropped from me, I created a class, according to the types of my letter, but I have a lot of errors, could you see what the error is ?? thank you)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244547/discussion-between-suzan-and-andrii-havrylyak).

Comment: Hi, could you help me solve this case successfully?), I added fromJson and toJson, now there are no errors), but the tasks are still not saved (Thank you)